# how to pass multiple input parameter to PHP from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i want to pass multiple input lines like `passwd = $("p#0").html();` to php file with parameter.

but, only pass one line with parameter and how can carry these many `passwd`lines.

In `pass.js`,

```js
//Authentication
var j = 0;
function login(){
var 
    // var passwd = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    passwd = $("p#0").html();
    passwd += $("p#5").html();
    passwd += $("p#10").html();
    passwd += $("p#15").html();
    passwd += $("p#28").html();
    passwd += $("p#25").html();
    passwd += $("p#22").html();
    passwd += $("p#32").html();
    var inpasswd = $(":text").val();
    if(passwd==inpasswd){
        location.href="somepage.php?w1=" + inpasswd + "";
    }else if(j==0){
        $("#info").html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert' style='margin-bottom: 0.3rem;'><i class='fas fa-exclamation'></i> The password is incorrect.</div>");
        j++;
    }
```

In `somepage.php`,

```php
<?php include("confs/config.php"); 

    $w1 = $_GET['w1'];
    echo $w1;
?>
```

index.php

```html
<tr>
    <td><div class="randamNumberBoxRadius"><p id="44">44</p></div></td>
    <td><div class="randamNumberBoxRadius"><p id="45">45</p></div></td>
    <td><div class="randamNumberBoxRadius"><p id="46">46</p></div></td>
    <td><div class="randamNumberBoxRadius"><p id="47">47</p></div></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: can you add desired output?

Comment: what is the typical content of `$("p#0").html()` for instance - or any of them. Is it a single word ?

Comment: It seems very week authentication.

Comment: ok,sir , i will add it

Comment: Thank Bro RamRaider ,that is input id field carry from `index.html` to `pass.js`.

Comment: `location.href="somepage.php?w1=" + passwd;` I think you are just using the wrong variable currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are concating the javascript variable just add PIPE in betwwen the password like

```
var password = '123'+'|'+'4567'+'|'+'123454';
```

like this when you receive this in your php function you can explode the string with '|' and get an array

```
$password = explode('|', $_GET['w1']);
```

so $password is an array now and you can perform whatever action you wanted on it

Comment: thank sir, but how can i pass `p#0+p#5+p#10` input lines to another php page

Comment: You can serialize them and save into localStorage or session and then access anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

use passwd instead of inpasswd

```
location.href="somepage.php?w1=" + passwd + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize your div or form and pass to php url.
Please check link[serialize in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)